# How to use IntDef annotation from another class

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to use `@ScreenOrientation` from `android.content.pm.ActivityInfo`. Its declaration:

```
@IntDef({
        SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED,
        SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE,
        ...
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ScreenOrientation {}
```

Compiler can't resolve it if I use it like this:

```
public abstract class ActivityBase extends ActionBarActivity {

    @ScreenOrientation
    protected abstract int getPhoneOrientation();    
}
```

`import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.*;` doesn't help.
`@android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.ScreenOrientation` doesn't help too.

I have annotations library in gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0'
```

Is it possible at all or the annotation is just hidden somehow?

Comment: Late suggestion: Which sdks are you targeting? The intdef for screen orientation is in the source since version 5.0.0 and not before. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @funglejunk `targetSdkVersion 22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the annotation is indeed hidden - if you look at `ActivityInfo` (currently line 313):
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.java

you'll see that there's an `@hide` annotation on it, thus preventing us from directly using it in our apps.